# String Array insertion problem

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to create a string array where user will give the input and data will be stored in array..I have no clue how to do that-(I read several C books)
Any help ll be appreciated
What I tried so far:

```
int choice;
    printf("enter the number of the strings: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
char **str=(char **)malloc(100);
    int i;



    for(i=0;i<choice;i++)
    {
        printf("enter %dth element ",i+1);
            str[i]=(char *)malloc(10);
        scanf("%s",str[i]);
    }
    printf("%s",str[0]);
```

Comment: You just need to read more I guess, this is very basic and basic skills will enable you to do it.

Comment: yes it should! but problem is that program is terminating !

Comment: I should hope it terminates! I'd hate to run a program that I expect to terminate and it just goes on forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You will have to allocate and initialize space for each string before reading them in. If you know he length of your input string then malloc/calloc that much space else guess a size but that would be wastage of space.

for(i=0;i<choice;i++)
     {
         printf("enter %dth element ",i+1);
         str[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*length);
         memset(str[i],0,length);
         scanf("%s",str[i]);
     }
```

Comment: Yeah dynamic allocation is the way to go. But usually when you are doing input like this you do not know the size of the string, so some large buffer is used, copied, and flushed.

Comment: str[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*length);
this line does not work!

Comment: you will have to specify the "length" ...but what Jonathan suggests is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating any spaces for the strings. If you are ok with bounded arrays you could define str as `char str[100][128]` to have 100 strings up to 128 chars each. At least until you learn some basic dynamic allocation.

Comment: i know dynamic allocation-I can do that

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this correctly, you have defined a pointer to an array of 100 chars. What you really want is 'choice' arrays of length 100 of chars I think `char str[choice][100]`

and then you can use your array as you have for the reading and printing of string input.